# Calling new methods on older versions does not work

Tags: android, lint

no lint prompt:

```
new MediaMetadataRetriever().close();
```

Android Studio：
Calling new methods on older versions switch is on
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsi4U.png

case 1:

```
compileSdkVersion=29
minSdkVersion=19
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5ns.png

case 2:

```
compileSdkVersion=29  
minSdkVersion=18
```

lint prompt: Call requires API level 29 (current min is 18)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BscMa.png

Why the first case lint doesn't prompt?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73755331

Answer (score 0):

It's like the original lint problem.