# Android studio doesn't warn usage of new-api. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

My Android Studio version:

- version: 4.2.2
- Settings->Inspections-> Calling new methods on older versions: **DID CHECK** (severity: error)

My project:

- compileSdkVersion **30**
- minSdkVersion **21**
- targetSdkVersion **30**

My snippet code:

```
myActivity.getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
```

Method **`getCurrentWindowMetrics()`** of class `WindowManager` is **ONLY available** on Android 11 (see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics())

**My question:**

why doesn't Android Studio warn me when calling new method:`getCurrentWindowMetrics` on older OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug happens when using `navigation-fragment-ktx` library version 2.4.x. It's fixed in recent versions, see a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242134775).

Comment: Finally, one guy understood me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They mention in the top right corner that they added it in the new Api level 30. So indirectly they say it is available since that version. But I'm with you, that it is confusing because of the missing backward compatibility.

[image: Indirect warning]